# How to retrieve the link and description in a custom file field twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a field `field_file`. I've created a template `field--field_file.html.twig`.

How can I access the link, description (and attributes and icon ) separately in this file?

I have:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

which just spits out themed content.

I've debugged with dump() and there seems like the possibility of at least retrieving the 'description' somehow, but item.description does not work, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File link: `{{ file_url(item.content['#file'].getFileUri()) }}`

File description: `{{ item.content['#description'] }}`